# Refcount Observable does not emit on second subscription

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

refCount is behaving unexpectedly in this use case. It's like because there was an initial subscription it does not emit again on the second subscription.

Why doesn't refCount() emit for the second subscription?

```
// Why does this test fail?
@Test
fun `refCount - on second subscription - emits value`() {
    val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()

    val observable = subject
            .doOnNext { System.out.println("This emits for second subscriber") }
            .replay(1)
            .refCount()
            .doOnNext { System.out.println("This does NOT emit for second subscriber") }

    // This line causes the test to fail.
    observable.takeUntil(Observable.just(Unit)).test()

    subject.onNext(2)

    val subscriber = observable.take(1).test()
    val finished = subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    assertTrue(finished)
}
```

Comment: `takeUntil` runs the other source first, which immediately disposes the upstream.

Comment: @akarnokd Exactly. But refCount should be able to resubscribe after the second subscriber kicks in. Updated that line to remove `dispose()` to avoid confusion

Comment: @akarnokd is the question clear? I feel like there's some confusion. Also are you implying that the upstream is no longer useable? We do see the subject emitting for the second subscriber (see the logs) but does not go through the `refCount`.

Comment: There is no confusion here, that line breaks the internals of replay/refCount in a peculiar way. This is a bug in RxJava and I posted [#6296](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6296) with the relevant Java unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @akarnokd mentioned, this was a bug and fixed in RxJava2 v2.2.12
[Link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v2.2.12)